# Referencing instance method 'stringify()' on 'Collection' requires the types 'Int' and 'Stringify' be equivalent

Tags: swift, protocols

I made an protocol Stringify to convert Types that implement the protocol to a String.

```
protocol Stringify {
    func stringify() -> String
}

extension Collection where Iterator.Element == Stringify {
    /// changes all the elements in the collection to a String
    func stringify() -> [String] {
        var strings = [String]()
        if let elements = self as? [Stringify] {
            for element in elements {
                strings.append(element.stringify())
            }
        }
        return strings
    }
}

extension Int: Stringify {
    func stringify() -> String {
        return String(self)
    }
}

extension Double: Stringify {
    func stringify() -> String {
        return String(self)
    }
}


let test = [5,6,7]

/// does work
[6,5,34].stringify()


/// does not work -> Error alert
test.stringify()
```

But when I set a collection of Ints to a property and using then stringify() on it, it does not work.

Error:

> Referencing instance method 'stringify()' on 'Collection' requires the
>   types 'Int' and 'Stringify' be equivalent

If I use it directly everything is going fine.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Replace `Iterator.Element == Stringify` by `Iterator.Element : Stringify`

Comment: What is the difference?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element == Stringify
```

has a “same type requirement” and defines an extension for collections whose elements are of the type  `Stringify`. But `test` is an array of `Int`, i.e. the elements *conform* to the `Stringify` protocol. So what you want is

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element : Stringify
```

or, equivalently,

```
extension Collection where Element : Stringify
```

The reason that

```
/// does work
[6,5,34].stringify()
```

compiles with your original definition is that the compiler infers the type of the array as `[Stringify]` from the context.

```
let test: [Stringify] = [5,6,7]
test.stringify()
```

would compile as well.

---

Note that there is no need to cast `self` in the extension method. You can simplify the implementation to

```
func stringify() -> [String] {
    var strings = [String]()
    for element in self {
        strings.append(element.stringify())
    }
    return strings
}
```

or just

```
func stringify() -> [String] {
    return self.map { $0.stringify() }
}
```